# Why was there no secret identity or blindspot created for Detective Fusco?

Tags: plot-explanation, person-of-interest

When Samaritan goes online in *Person of Interest*, the Machine creates 7 secret identities and Root accquires 7 servers to make a blindspot to save people related to the Machine.
Below are the seven persons:

1. Harold Finch
2. John Reese
3. Sameen Shaw
4. Samantha Groves (Root)
5. Daniel Casey
6. Daizo
7. Jason Greenfield

Samaritan is smart enough to find the connection of Harold with Grace Hendricks, even when he is not meeting her and she believes him dead. On the other hand,
Detective Fusco is helping them from a long time. He had been on many places with them and also actively helped them.
Then why is the Machine not needed to create a blindspot for him?
In other words, why is Samaritan not able to find the connection between Detective Fusco and John and Harold.

Answer (score 3):

> Why Samaritan is not able to find the connection between Detective Fusco and John & Harold.

Fusco is on the *radar* but there's a difference between being aware of someone and assigning them as a **threat**. For the most part, Fusco is just "interacting" with the Machine Gang by encrypted phones etc. and going about his normal job as a NYPD detective...or at least so it appears.

**More Importantly** - Fusco doesn't know about the existence of the Machine or Samaritan until Season 5.

It's only when he begins an investigation into the suspicious rise in missing persons that, unknown to Fusco, Samaritan has arranged, his activities are viewed in a new light. This leads to Samaritan labeling him as a "possible obstructionist". (*S5 Episode - Shotseeker*)

Comment: Add to this that Fusco also had a natural reason to interact with Reese, since he was his partner at work.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson He is partner in season 4 , but they are interactiong from almost start. I was looking from that perspective. Not considered season 4 as identities were created before season4.